# PostgreSql Integer out of range error when inserting small numbers into integer fields

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm getting an "integer out of range" error in postgres, though none of the numbers inserted are 'big'. They are well under a million. 
The query is generated via the Django ORM, and is pretty standard looking.
Any idea what I'm missing here?
Thanks!

```
# INSERT INTO "index_index" ("word_id", "ad_id", "field", "position", "created_at") VALUES (98036, 703906, E'y.x', 0, E'2011-09-29 22:02:40.252332') RETURNING "index_index"."id";
ERROR:  integer out of range

# \d index_index;

Table "public.index_index"
   Column   |           Type           |                        Modifiers                         
------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
 id         | integer                  | not null default nextval('index_index_id_seq'::regclass)
 word_id    | integer                  | not null
 ad_id      | integer                  | not null
 field      | character varying(50)    | not null
 position   | integer                  | not null
 created_at | timestamp with time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "index_index_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_index_ad_id" btree (ad_id)
    "index_index_word_id" btree (word_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "index_index_ad_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (ad_id) REFERENCES campaigns_ad(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "index_index_word_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (word_id) REFERENCES index_word(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Comment: What's the value of `nextval('index_index_id_seq')` ?  Have you outgrown your id column?  nextval returns a bigint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe the sequence has exceeded the max. value for an integer (2147483647). As a sequence is based on a bigint, this is possible.

You can test that using `SELECT nextval('index_index_id_seq')`